# How can I send gcm-ccs notification using XMPP in node.js?

Tags: android, node.js, google-cloud-messaging

I had try [node-gcm-xmpp](https://github.com/jacobp100/node-gcm-ccs), and also trying to use [node-xmpp-client](https://github.com/node-xmpp/node-xmpp-client) in nodejs which is having build error.

Comment: Please post the error and also some implementation from where the error is evoked.